# KeyRelease won't happen until next KeyPress

Tags: keyboard

Running Ubuntu desktop 18.04.4

When I reboot, everything is fine.  But after some time (and maybe some combination of keys that I haven't figured out yet) my keyboard seems to get stuck in a state where my KeyRelease is stuck until another KeyPress happens.  In other words, if I watch xevents with xev, then this will happen:

```
press key 'd'
   See KeyPress 'd'
..
press key 'a'
   See KeyRelease 'd'
   See KeyPress 'a'
```

I've tried resetting my keyboard setup a number of ways:

```
dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration
```

And also:

```
setxkbmap -layout us
setxkbmap -option
```

This leaves me with:

```
% setxkbmap -query
rules:      evdev
model:      pc105
layout:     us,us
variant:    ,
```

And I've checked to make sure sticky keys are off:

```
% xkbset -sticky ; xkbset q | grep Sticky-Keys
Sticky-Keys = Off
```

But the problem persists.  Disconnecting the keyboard and reboot do not help.  It happens on multiple keyboards.

Comment: Very fair point - i'll do it right now, normally I put that info in there.

Comment: Have you tried unplugging the keyboard or using a different one?

Comment: Yup - and it happens on my builtin keyboard as well as my external keyboard.